# FInd javascript-links with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

Is there any way to find javascript-links on a webpage with python? I use mechanize and I can't find all the links I want. I want the url on the pictures on this site: http://500px.com/popular

Comment: can you post a usecase?

Comment: A sample page with expected output would be helpful.

Comment: want the url on the pictures on this site: http://500px.com/popular

Answer (score 1):

With just BeautifulSoup this is quite easy:

```
js_links = soup.select('a[href^="javascript:"]')
```

This selects all `<a>` elements that have a `href` attribute whose value starts with `javascript:`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <html><body>
... <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Not a javascript link</a>
... <a name="target">Not a link, no href</a>
... <a href="javascript:alert('P4wned');">Javascript link (with scary message)</a>
... <a href="javascript:return False">Another javascript link</a>
... </body></html>
... ''')
>>> for link in soup.select('a[href^="javascript:"]'):
...     print link['href'], link.get_text()
... 
javascript:alert('P4wned'); Javascript link (with scary message)
javascript:return False Another javascript link
```